# Redirecting output in unix creates corrupted files

Tags: unix, sh

I am new to unix and scripting language.
I wrote the following script and called it `scr.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sha  
ls > file1  
ls > file2
```

I run it using:`sh scr.sh`
This creates the two files, however the file `file1` is corrupted and the file `file2` is ok (when I write `cat file1` it writes `No such file or directory`. However, when I write `cat file2` it works fine)

I feel it something simple ( maybe closing file ) that I forgot to do.
Can anyone help me please?
I may use any other unix scripts as well.

Comment: `#!/bin/sha` You have a sha shell ?

Comment: Re: "when I write `cat file1` it writes `No such file or directory`": Are you saying that `file1` doesn't exist? Or are you saying that it actually contains the text `No such file or directory`?

Comment: I see it exists. However, I can't really read it.

Comment: I now did the ls function to see the files in the directory, and I see it created files called `file2` and `file1?`. Do you know Where the `?` came from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `no such file or directory` is the error from your bad shebang: `#!/bin/sha`  cat is displaying the error message.

Bourne shell is `#!/bin/sh`  on systems that have Bourne natively installed - like Solaris.  It is remotely possible you have a sha shell, but given your error message I don't think so.  Try:

```
#/bin/sha
ls
```

as a script and you will see the error on the tty screen.

Comment: Did you do what I asked. In a script?  Since that does not seem possible: Just type /bin/sha  and see what you get.  If you cannot do what we ask we'll never be able to help you.  What you are saying, based on what you show, makes very little sense.

Comment: I did it.  I see it created files called file2 and file1?. Do you know Where the `?` came from?

Comment: The problem is that I expect to find file called `file1`. However, I have a file called `file1?` instead. Can you help me with this please?

Comment: If that is the question, then ls on some systems will translate unprintable (meaning garbage usually) characters into a ?.  For  a file name unix allows ANY character except an ASCII 0 -- NUL.  So you can have junk characters in a filename even '\n' or a space.  ls only pretties this up (makes a ?) when writing to a tty so try this:  ls file* | od -c from the command line.  You will probable see some weird character at the end like this: f i l e \0321.

Comment: It writes `f i l e 1 \r \n` and `f i l e 2 \n`.

Comment: It seems that the `\r` is the problem. It may be because I write the script in windows and put it on the unix machine using ssh. Do you now what can i do to make the `\r` disappear?

Comment: Don't use a windows editor, or change the carriage control in scr.sh with dos2unix (sometimes called dos2ux): dos2unix scr.sh scr.sh.   Read up on your version of dos2unix before you run it.